# An example for __add__,__sub__,__mul__ and __div__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have no idea how I can use these methods. Would you please provide some simple examples?

Comment: You don't use these methods directly they are called indirectly by the operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`

Comment: Check out this explanation of magic methods. http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

Comment: In my code "/" doesn't call __div__. What could be the problem?
It says: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'RationalNumber' and 'RationalNumber'"

Comment: @Rakanoth Ok, so sounds like you have a concrete problem with a concrete implementation. Can you put up the code so we can better address your issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, let me make a NonNegative:

```
 class NonNegative(object):
   def __init__(self, x):
     if x < 0: raise Exception()
     self.x = x

   @property
   def value(self):
     return self.x

   @value.setter
   def set_value(self, that):
     if that < 0: raise Exception()
     self.x = that

   def __add__(self, x):
     if isinstance(x, NonNegative):
       return NonNegative(x.value + self.x)
     else:
       return NotImplemented
```

Used like this:

```
   a = NonNegative(1)
   b = NonNegative(2)
   c = a + b
```

so calling `+` would delegate to calling `__add__`.

Comment: Don't raise an error, return the `NotImplemented` singleton instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good critique. Updating.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you point to somewhere which explains this? Very curious.

Comment: @Annan search for `NotImplemented` in the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).